Codeigniter не может найти базу данных docker-а
Появляется ошибка когда хочу достать данные из таблицы
CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException
Unable to connect to the database.
Main connection [MySQLi]: No such file or directory. Миграции бд работают.
public array $default = [
        'DSN'          => '',
        'hostname'     => 'localhost',
        'username'     => 'root',
        'password'     => 'cod31gn1t3',
        'database'     => 'codeigniter_db',
        'DBDriver'     => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix'     => '',
        'pConnect'     => false,
        'DBDebug'      => true,
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat'     => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'      => '',
        'encrypt'      => false,
        'compress'     => false,
        'strictOn'     => false,
        'failover'     => [],
        'port'         => 3306,
        'numberNative' => false,
    ];

это не работает для извлекания данных , что нужно сделать?
модель
class CommentsModel extends \CodeIgniter\Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';
}

контроллер
public function comments():string
    {
        $model = new \App\Models\CommentsModel();
        $data = $model->findAll();
        return view('comments');
    }

